Definition of empirical distribution on a function class
Let $X$ be a random variable on a measurable space $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algbera on $\mathcal{X}$. Let $\mathbb{P}_X$ be the distribution of $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the Hilbert space of square-integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t the distribution $\mathbb{P}_X$.
Define the empirical distribution of $X$ which acts on $f\in\mathcal{F}$ by $\mathbb{P}_{X,n}(f) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i)$, where $\{X_i\}_{\{i=1,\ldots,n\}}$ are iid copies of $X$. My question is: since elements $\mathcal{F}$ are really equivalence classes, is this mapping well-defined? In particular, choose two $\mathbb{P}_X$-equal almost everywhere functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, is the mapping $\mathbb{P}_{X,n}(f_1)$ and $\mathbb{P}_{X,n}(f_2)$ considered the same? I guess so, because the fact that they are $\mathbb{P}_X$-equal almost everywhere, $\{X_i\}$ has zero-probability of being realized in the $\mathbb{P}_X$-null set where $f_1$ and $f_2$ differ.

Indeed, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equal $\mathbb{P}_X$-almost everywhere, then by invoking the union bound,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{P}_{X,n}(f_1) \neq \mathbb{P}_{X,n}(f_1))
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}(f_1(X_i) \neq f_2(X_i)) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}_X(f_1 \neq f_2) \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
So, $[f] \mapsto \mathbb{P}_{X,n}(f)$ is a well-defined function from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
